# Рефлексия: странно запускается метод

Tags: c#, рефлексия

Господа, есть такой код:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
class a
{
    public a()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(1);
    }
    public a(int x)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(x);
    }
    public a(bool b, double z)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Bla");
    }
    public void Z()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Z");
    }
    public void S(int x)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("S");
    }
    public int Z(int z)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("int Z"); return 5;
    }
    public void S(double z)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("double s");
    }
}
class b
{
    static void Main()
    {
        ConstructorInfo[] ci = typeof(a).GetConstructors();
        MethodInfo[] mi = typeof(a).GetMethods();
        foreach (ConstructorInfo CI in ci)
        {
            ParameterInfo[] pi = CI.GetParameters();

            if (pi.Length == 1 && pi[0].ParameterType.Name == typeof(int).Name)
            {
                object[] o = new object[pi.Length];
                o[pi.Length - 1] = 4;
                foreach (MethodInfo MI in mi)
                {
                    ParameterInfo[] MPI = MI.GetParameters();
                    if (MPI.Length == 0)
                    {
                        MI.Invoke(CI.Invoke(o), null);
                    }
                    if (MI.ReturnParameter.Name == typeof(int).Name && MPI.Length == 1)
                    {
                        object[] mo = new object[1] { 6 };
                        MI.Invoke(CI.Invoke(o), mo);
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Здесь я пробую, как работает рефлексивный вызов метода и создание объекта. Однако я наткнулся на чудеса в c#. Прогоняя программу в пошаговом режиме, я вижу, как программа в первый раз вызывает инструкцию:

```
if (MPI.Length == 0)
{
MI.Invoke(CI.Invoke(o), null);
}
```

Ну и, как следствие, создается объект (при этом выводится на консоль цифра 4) и запускается соответствующий метод (который выводит букву Z). Однако при дальнейшей пошаговой отладке я вижу, как компилятор опять входит в эту инструкцию, но при этом создается объект (и выводится цифра 4), НО НЕ запускается метод. ПОЧЕМУ? 
То есть я ожидаю вывода на консоль что-то типа
4Z4Z4Z и т. д. А получаю 4Z444.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Разобрался!!!

Я забыл, что при получении списка методов так же идут унаследованные методы. Для того, чтобы так не было, нужно ввести

```
MethodInfo[] mi = typeof(a).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);
```